# How to Disable HTTP Proxy for specific requests?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have an `org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder` that is configured during initialization to use a proxy by calling `useSystemProperties()` in the builder.

```
org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder client = HttpClients.custom()
    .useSystemProperties()...build();
```

I would like to disable the proxy for certain request? How can I achieve this? Is this possible by adding`HttpRequestInterceptor` interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a to simple approach but I will just create two instances. One with the proxy and one without. Then I will use the good one depending on the request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is would be a simple and easy solution, except that This HttpClientBuilder is wrapped in a class and given to clients to use it. Users of this of this class are the ones issuing the requests and I don't have control over it. Ideally, I would like to intercept their calls and modify the proxy.

Comment: There is no need to create multiple instances of HttpClient. Use a custom `HttpRoutePlanner` instead.

Comment: @oleg Thanks! I think this is what I will do!

Comment: @iah10 Maybe as suggested by @Oleg `HttpRoutePlanner ` can help.See this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25568306/1140748. Please tell me if it helps. I probably will delete this answer...